Can more concentrated tomato products increase stomach acidity?
It appears from Internet sources that tomatoes have a pH of 4-4.5, as does tomato puree/paste.
I’m wondering about the fact that paste is more concentrated.  Will eating say a teaspoon of tomato paste cause a greater acidity/lower pH than eating one whole tomato?
If you consider a soup made with a tomatoe base(say 15 crushed) tomatoes and a soup with more alkaline vegetables and two tomatoes I guess the acidity in the later will be brought down by the more alkaline vegetables and so will definitely be higher than 4.5. What might the acidity be of one serving of the tomato-based soup?

Rather depends on what's in the tin. Citric acid as an acidity regulator/ripening agent is added in some cases. Species of tomato used (and ripeness) would make quite a difference too. Only way to be sure is to measure it.
